# Tkinter entry get unicode content error

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode-string, tkinter-entry

I have a strange problem trying to get some values from a Tkinter Entry. Basically if in the Entry I have a no-ascii value and use get() content, sometime I have a correct unicode string and sometime I have and ascii string a-la unicode without the canonical 'u'. Here my code:

```
def create():
    try:
        cols = []
        values = []                
        for name in names:
            if (pk <> name):
                if (name in fk_columns):
                    cols.append(name)
                    values.append(box[name].get())
                else:                        
                    cols.append(name)
                    values.append(entry[name].get())                        
        print values                        
        dbutils.create(mDBname, mTable,cols,values)
        frame.master.destroy()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("New record", "Record created") 
        scrolled_view(root,mDBname,mTable,'g',0, editable)           
    except Exception, err:
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", err)           

def update():
    try:
        cols = []
        new_values = []
        old_values = []
        i = 0
        for name in names:
            if (name in fk_columns):
                cols.append(name)
                new_values.append(box[name].get())
            else:                        
                cols.append(name)                    
                new_values.append(entry[name].get())                                       
            if rows[record][i] == None:
                old_values.append('')
            else:
                old_values.append(rows[record][i]) 
            i = i + 1
        print new_values 
        dbutils.update(mDBname, mTable, cols, new_values, old_values)
        frame.master.destroy()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Update", "Record updated")
        scrolled_view(root,mDBname,mTable,'g',0, editable)            
    except Exception, err:
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", err)
```

So the problem is if I use the "create" function and I have an Entry with the value for example "John Canà", when I print the values in the shell (notice the "print values" before the call to dbutils) I got:

```
[u'John Can\xe0', 'Amministrazione']
```

and the function work without error.

When I use the update function, even updating just the second value not the one with "John Canà" on the python shell (calling print new_values before the call to dbutils) I got:

```
['17', 'John Can\xe0', 'Marketing']
```

The string 'John Can\xe0' is without the 'u'. This in end produce the classic error "ordinal not in range 128'. So my question why the same Entry.get() call produce this different behaviour and how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if it's what you're looking for, I am showing you the behavior of what have tested so far:

```
>>> name = u'John Can\xe0'
>>> name = bytes(name,"unicode_escape")
>>> name.decode('unicode_escape')
'John Canà' # This is the output
```

So to avoid `\xe0` in your string, proceed to a conversion before display any string

Comment: Thanks Lemayzeur, but this won't help. Basically what I have from db is name = 'John Can\xe0' which is like an unicode without the u prefix and I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: even without the prefix `u` like you said, it would work.  You store data in db with `\xe0`  and display them after `bytes(name,"unicode_escape").decode('unicode_escape')`. it will display `à`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to sqlalchemy raw query: when I create record (insert) the entry correctly handle the text as unicode (no plain string):

```
u'John Can\xe0'
```

When updating basically I make a raw select (via sqlalchemy) to populate entries, and the value

```
'John Can\xe0'
```

came from the raw select. Adding

```
'?charset=utf8'
```

to connection string solved the problem. 
The only thing don'tundestand is why Tkinter Entry correctly handle 'John Can\xe0' and not raise error. By the way now the code work!